# Passing a hashed string from controller to view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, hash, isset

I want to pass a hashed string from controller to view which as I know when we pass something, goes to session(right?).
Because of security issues (Not allowing users to edit phpsessid to get in), I don't want to use these:

`@if(session()->has('sth'))`

OR

`@if(isset($_SESSION['sth']))`

OR

`@if(session('sth'))`

You know why? because session just by being set(isset), will do the statements, however I want to check that `'sth'` in view with `Hash::check` to make sure that the value is equals to the value that I want.
Because if I don't do that some malicious people might create/edit phpsessid to access the information that I don't want.

Questions:
1.Am I right?

2.Is this normal to use `Hash::check` in view?

3.Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Comment: `I want to pass a hashed string from controller to view which as I know when we pass something, goes to session(right?).` No it's bound in the view.

Comment: Also, check the hashed string in the controller or in a service (if has any) but not in the view.

Comment: Thanks dear The Alpha :)

Comment: Laravel session is safe to use.

Comment: Dear Digitlimit, I know it's safe, but I wanted to prevent someone creating a phpsessid with any value, and if I used only isset, it would return true and the statement would be run, isn't it?